# How can I have two key_input methods in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have found that  I can only have one method  for key input. Bellow I have two methods (movementsprite, and movementspritevert) I have found that I can only have one work. If I initiate both, the top one runs, and the second one does nothing. Is there a way around this? Am I doing something wrong?

### Original Program

----Movement File------

```
    import pygame
    import os, sys
    from itertools import *
    from oryxsprites import *
    from oryxdisplay import *
    spritex = 320
    spritey = 320

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))
    def movementsprite():   

        global spritex

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 running = False
             elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                 if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     if spritex == 576:
                         spritex += 0
                     else:
                         spritex += 32 

                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:              
                     if spritex == 32:
                         spritex -= 0
                     else:
                         spritex -= 32

        return spritex
    def movementspritevert():   

        global spritey

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 running = False
             elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                 if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     if spritey == 576:
                         spritey += 0
                     else:
                         spritey += 32 

                 elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:              
                     if spritey == 32:
                         spritey -= 0
                     else:
                         spritey -= 32

        return spritey
```

-------Main File------]

```
running = True

while running:

    backgroundmain()
    pygame.display.set_caption('OryxGame')
    #pygame.display.set_icon(grasstile)
    movementsprite()
    movementspritevert()

    pygame.display.flip()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
             pygame.quit()
```

------Display file----

```
def backgroundmain():
    spritex = movementsprite()
    spritey = movementspritevert()
    backdrop = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 640, 640) 
    screen.fill((50,50,50))
    playingfeildwidth = (32, 608)
    playingfeildheight = (32, 608)

    screen.blit(warrior1, (spritex, spritey))
```

### ------Possible solution -------------

-Main File----

```
 while running:

    backgroundmain()
    pygame.display.set_caption('OryxGame')
    #pygame.display.set_icon(grasstile)
    movementsprite(events)
    movementspritevert(events)

    pygame.display.flip()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
             pygame.quit()
```

-----Display File-----

```
def backgroundmain():
    events = pygame.event.get()
    spritex = movementsprite(events)
    spritey = movementspritevert(events)
    backdrop = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 640, 640) 
    screen.fill((50,50,50))
    playingfeildwidth = (32, 608)
    playingfeildheight = (32, 608)
```

------Key Input File-----------

```
spritex = 320
spritey = 320
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))
def movementsprite(events):  
    global spritex
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in events:
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

             if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                 if spritex == 576:
                     spritex += 0
                 else:
                     spritex += 32 

             elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:              
                 if spritex == 32:
                     spritex -= 0
                 else:
                     spritex -= 32

    return spritex
def movementspritevert(events):   
    global spritey
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in events:
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

             if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                 if spritey == 576:
                     spritey += 0
                 else:
                     spritey += 32 

             elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:              
                 if spritey == 32:
                     spritey -= 0
                 else:
                     spritey -= 32

    return spritey
```

---Error---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Dropbox\oryxgame\oryxgame.py", line 12, in <module>
    backgroundmain()
  File "C:\Users\Eric\Dropbox\oryxgame\oryxdisplay.py", line 11, in backgroundmain
    spritey = movementspritevert(events)
TypeError: movementspritevert() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

----[Full Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zv37rzk2vzhtvg8/oryxgame%20-%20Eric.zip)----

Comment: Have you posted all of the code to demonstrate your problem? I don't see where either of these functions is called or referenced.

Comment: I added the rest of the files/code. I figure the problem would be in the Key-press section so I had only included that. @matt b

Comment: Why can't you make use of two globals in movementsprite, and simply handle the various cases there? Also, I note that you are effectively calling those two functions twice - in backgroundmain() you call movementsprite, and then within the same loop you call it again. You need only read the input once per loop.

Comment: I was trying to use both global's in movement sprite but it cause the sprite to move diagonally. @dwerner

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that event.get() removes the events from queue (see [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get)).  So, when your second function uses event.get(), there aren't any events remaining in the queue, unless they were able to slip in during the extremely short interval between calls.

To see this problem in action, put a  `print event`  after calling `for event in pygame.event.get()` in the first function, then try it in the second.

One way to fix this would be

```
    events = pygame.event.get()
    function1(events)
    function2(events)
```

Then use a for loop over `events` instead.

**EDIT:** to clarify how to implement

It's likely your code threw an error because `pygame.event.get()` was called before initializing pygame.  You could use something like,

```
def backgroundmain():
    events = pygame.event.get()                #save events
    spritex = movementsprite(events)           #added events arg
    spritey = movementspritevert(events)       #added events arg
    backdrop = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 640, 640) 
    screen.fill((50,50,50))
    playingfeildwidth = (32, 608)
    playingfeildheight = (32, 608)

    screen.blit(warrior1, (spritex, spritey))
```

Then, change the movement functions from this:

```
def movementspritevert():   

    #Do stuff ...

    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
         elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

to this:

```
def movementspritevert(events):   

    #Do stuff ...

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
```

The key is that every time you use event.get(), it will remove the events, so your next call won't get the same events.  Basically, if you want one key press to be used by all of  your movement functions, then save the events as a variable and pass that to the functions.

Comment: So I tried what you suggested.I added the `events = pygame.event.get()` to the top, above my funtions. I got an error `error: video system not initialized`.  so I removed the  `()`. I know I am doing this wrong. I added the changed code to the bottom of my question.  @Closed

Comment: It sounds like you used pygame.event.get() before pygame.init().  I updated my answer with one way you could make the changes.

Comment: So I got the error  `spritey = movementspritevert(events)`  then `TypeError: movementspritevert() takes no arguments (1 given)` Im not exactly sure what this means. Do you? @Closed

Comment: I don't think you changed your call to `def movementspritevert(events):`.  Look at what Closed wrote and copy that (just keep in mind he forgot to indent `running = False`)

Comment: No I did change that @hammythepig

Comment: @enrique2334 Hmm that's strange. That error means you're trying to give a function something when it doesn't need anything... you might still be calling the function from a different file you havn't changed yet maybe? Are you still calling it in the main program after `backgroundmain()`?

Comment: yes i am still calling it in the main program after backgroundmain(). I have tried it with and without `events` and have received the same error.

Comment: Thanks for catching the misindent!  Can you search your script for "def movementspritevert():"?  Like hammythepig said, it looks like it either didn't get changed (or is defined more than once).

Comment: No i checked twice it did get changed @Closed

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the Traceback of the error?  Have you looked at the line of code it refers to?

Comment: Okay I added the changed code, and the full error to the original question under possible solution @closed

Comment: It's hard to say.  Did you rename the file with `def movementsprite(events):`?  That is, are you importing the wrong file?  Try putting `print "TEST"` or something at the top of the --Key Input File--.  Be sure to put it in the one with the modified functions.  I think you might be loading the wrong file.  Also, you should take the `movementsprite` statements out of your --Main File--, since they don't do anything (and events isn't defined).

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I added a [copy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zv37rzk2vzhtvg8/oryxgame%20-%20Eric.zip) of the whole game If you want to get a better look. Thanks  @closed